# nodejs - connect with gmail-api

Tags: node.js

I want to let users to connect to my `node.js server` with their `gmail`. I have created a project in the `Google Developers Console`. Then use the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const google = require('googleapis');
const googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

const credentials = require('../link/of/some/file.json'); // google credential

let clientSecret = credentials.web.client_secret;
let clientId = credentials.web.client_id;
let redirectUrl = credentials.web.redirect_uris[0];

const SCOPES = [
   'https://mail.google.com/',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
];

let auth = new googleAuth();
let oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

app.get('/connect', (req, res) => {
   let authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: SCOPES
   });
   res.redirect(authUrl);
});
```

when `/connect` is called, it will redirect to google page to verify user.   After user give access of his/her account, google will automatically call the following api with a `code` query parameter:

```
app.get('/auth/callback', (req, res) => {
    // 'req.query.code' is provided by google
    return oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, (err, token) => {
       // token value:
       /*
          { 
             access_token: 'ya29.Gls2Ba_rXEA5EoBaFH5bPdDDzgaSWOtb0GSJcnaTP47Jh7HwHdF2ZJZOlQaCJBC5wjpq-sOLBVlIM9L8BMslVyHw22nveU0MwQ4iJPTq5vkjXDeitqtoYH8JO83w',
             refresh_token: '1/S0C3w-8vnqcrGE4Z2mSW9ctYkaitVuZquBSJ0WJJHUs',
             token_type: 'Bearer',
             expiry_date: 1514897380473 
          }
       */
    });
});
```

Now, My problem is, in the above token value, I cannot understand how can I get gmail address from that token. What am I missing???

Any Suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**
I have solve this problem, just calling `getProfile`, where userId is `me`. My code is given below:

```
const SCOPES = [
   'https://mail.google.com/',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
];

app.get('/auth/callback', (req, res) => {

return oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, (err, token) => {
    oauth2Client.credentials = token;
    var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
    gmail.users.getProfile({
      auth: oauth2Client,
      userId: "me",
    }, function(error, response) {
          console.log("getProfile : ", {error, response});
          /*
             output:
               {
                 emailAddress: 'some.address@gmail.com',
                 messagesTotal: xxx,
                 threadsTotal: xxx,
                 historyId: 'xxxxx' 
              } 
          */
      });

    });
});
```

Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

the first steps I would suggest is to store your token somewhere so you don't request it all the time.

Then when you recieve the token you put it in `oauth2Client.credentials`

```
 oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      //TODO: Save token somewhere

      oauth2Client.credentials = token;

    });
```

Then you use the `oauth2Client` to do API calls

```
 var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    userId: 'me',
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var labels = response.labels;
    if (labels.length == 0) {
      console.log('No labels found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Labels:');
      for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var label = labels[i];
        console.log('- %s', label.name);
      }
    }
  });
```